# Issue with loading background image using CSS (Aptana Studio)

Tags: css, aptana, aptana3

Im using following CSS to set a background-image for my menu

```
#menuContainer
{
    background:url('../images/main-bg.png') repeat-x;
}
```

My CSS is inside

```
~/styles/site.css
```

and my image is inside

```
~/images/main-bg.png
```

The problem is this works perfectly in Chrome but it's not working in Firefox.
But if change the URL to

```
#menuContainer
{
    background:url('images/main-bg.png') repeat-x;
}
```

It starts working in Firefox and in Chrome it doesn't work.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Just noticed that your image folder name is `img` and in stylesheet you calling the folder as `images`. Is that a type error???

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo my images are inside the folder called "images".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a mistake on my side. All the time I was using Aptana Studio to check my site. When I run the page from Aptana it automatically opens up Firefox, when it's does it doesn't render the images. It uses something called Firefox internal server. I think the problem is there. Finally I tried just opening the web page in Firefox and Chrome by right clicking on the Index.html in windows explorer it works perfectly in both browsers. Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
#menuContainer
{
    background-image:url('./../images/main-bg.png') repeat-x; /* or './../img/main-bg.png' */
}
```

If you have a domain name (or running localhost), then you should try using absolute path to get the image, as I feel the issue is with how the browsers are resolving the relative paths:

```
#menuContainer
{
    background-image:url('wwww.example.com/images/main-bg.png') repeat-x; /* or 'localhost:8080/images/main-bg.png' - please replace 8080 with the port you are using. */
}
```

Comment: Where is your html file? is it at '~/*.html' ? Just as a test, can you move the html file to styles folder and check whether your former code, or my code works in both browsers?

Comment: My html file is in root folder. Moving the html into styles folder is not an option and it's not working anyway. Yes I also think it's something related to resolving relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

replace with this

```
#menuContainer
{
    background:url('../img/main-bg.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Check comment on the question.